# Display for specific id in .Net Core EF

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

This is what I want:

```
`@foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EnHeading "where id = 18")
                </td>
             </tr>
        }
```

how would i go about doing this?
Thanks

Comment: Do you want to set the id of the html element to 18 or only output that display if the item.id = 18?

Comment: the latter, only display the item.id=18

Answer (score 1):

Just add an if for displaying the item.

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @if (item.id == 18)
            {
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EnHeading)
            }
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: Why not Model.Where(x => x.id == 18) so not all the items are looped.

Comment: @AjmalAmirzad when using `Where` it is still iterating through all items; if you want to stop the iteration as soon as the match is found, use `First` or `FirstOrDefault`.

Comment: @SebastianHofmann  you are right, I was on my mobile, forgot to add it.